# Images not appearing as planned, I'm trying to change images in a JFrame using JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

My code is

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Change pic");
ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");
frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth(),image.getIconHeight());
frame.add(new JLabel(image));
Thread.sleep(3000);
frame.add(new JLabel(image1));
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

When using the above code the first image("image") doesn't appear and only the second image("image 2") appears. And even when not using the line Thread.sleep(3000) it gives the same result.
But when i'm writing my code as

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Change pic");
ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");
frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth(),image.getIconHeight());
frame.add(new JLabel(image));
frame.setVisible(true);
Thread.sleep(3000);
frame.add(new JLabel(image1));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then the first image ("image") appears on top of the second image("image1") and i could only see the second image when I extend the Frame to the right?

So my question is why for the second code the first image("image") appears on the top? And what changes do i have to make so the second image("image1") replaces the first image("image")  after 3 second?

Sorry, if the question is dumb. And any help will be appreciated.
Actually, I'm trying to develop a remote desktop sharing application and I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`. Add components without specifying a `BorderLayout` position will automatically add it to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Each position can only have *one* component. The last component you add will be the only one visible. See more at [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
2. Avoid using `Thread.sleep`. If you want animation, use a `javax.swing.Timer`. See more at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Using this method, you can do something like this

   ```
   JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(image);
   ...
   Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            iconLabel.setIcon(image1);
        }
   }); 
   timer.setRepeats(false);
   timer.start();
   ```

   Instead of trying to add a new label, just change the icon.
3. Also don't set the size of your frame. Just pack it. The image will set the preferred size of the `JLabel` for you and `pack`ing the frame will assure the icon is fully visible.

As an aside, when you add components *after* the container is visible, you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container.

---

Try running this example. Just put in your path to the image icons.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangeIcon {

    public ChangeIcon() {
        final ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
        final ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");
        final JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(image);

        Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                iconLabel.setIcon(image1);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(iconLabel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChangeIcon();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But that didn't happened, for the second code the first image is the image that is properly displaced, the last added image appeared only slightly to the right

Comment: Not sure without a runnable example, but try using the Timer instead of Thread.sleep. You're better off

Comment: No sir I actually tried it and that's what happened the first image is appearing properly but the second image is not displaced well, just to the right. Sir you may try it in our computer.

Comment: Run my example above see what happens. Put in your image paths.

Comment: Sir, its working fine. Thank you very much. I got the solution, but still it confuses me why my code didn't work?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure unless you have a complete runnable example we can test out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50080/discussion-between-dividedbyzero-and-peeskillet)

Comment: With the first code, you see only the second image because the frame is not visible until the second image is shown. In the second code, the frame is visible _before_ add the second label. In that case you need to revalidate and repaint the frame. You must do this whenever adding components to a containter _after_ the container is already visible.